# Search a value in associative array and return key

Tags: php, arrays, search

Given this associative array:

```
$currencies = [
    'foo' => [
        'name' => 'EUR',
        'symbol' => '€'
    ],
    'bar' => [
        'name' => 'USD',
        'symbol' => '$'
    ],
    'baz' => [
        'name' => 'GBP',
        'symbol' => '£'
    ],
];
```

How can I search for a `name` and retrieve key in a concise manner? I.e. searching for `EUR` returns `foo`.

I could loop, but I'd prefer a shorter way, if it exists...

Thanks

Comment: All operations with arrays (except accessing by key) are done via loop. If you don't see the loop - it's hidden under the hood.

Answer (score 0):

```
function searchCurrencies($currencies, $name) {
  foreach($currencies as $k => $v) {
    if($v->name==$name)
      return $k;
  };
};
```

Comment: Hi, just for you to know: when you answer a question try to post something more complete than just the code, maybe add a little explanation of what was the author's error and how you fixed it. I'm telling you this because your answer has been flagged for deletion in the "Low Quality Post" queue. You can edit your answer using the "Edit" button , or by clicking here: [edit]